# Why didn't STEM warn Grey about the sole print at the murder scene?

Tags: upgrade-2018

In the Cyberpunk type movie *Upgrade*, I know STEM is an Artificial Intelligence. If STEM warned Grey about fingerprints and the need to remove them, why can't it warn him about his **shoe sole print** at the first murder scene?

Comment: SPOILERS:  remember the ultimate goal is to *break" Grey.  So walking a fine line between helping & gaining Grey's trust and hindering him to keep him under pressure at all times is part of the plan.